# Pass bash array to expect script

Tags: arrays, bash, tcl, expect

I have a bash script that calls an expect script like so

```
$SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY/my_expect_script.sh $my_bash_array
```

I can pass a variable over, it seems, and use it. 
For this example the variable seems to be in `[lindex $argv 0]`.

From bash, it will be a bunch of values, e.g. `1 2 3 4 5`.

I am trying to figure out how to use expect to grab this variable, save it to an array then loop through the array to spit out multiple commands one at a time.

So my output should be something like

```
send command 1 \r
send command 2 \r
```

etc., until it reaches the end of the array.

I thought in expect I would assign it like

```
array set myArray [lindex $argv 0]
```

but it looks like I am wrong.

Would anyone have any good places I can look that might explain going from bash to expect better, or know how to do this? I assume its relatively simple, but expect is very iffy with me in some aspects.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you explain that you can access the variable using `[lindex $argv 0]`. Why, then, are you trying to use `[lindex $argv 5]` instead?

Comment: `$my_bash_array` only expands to the first element of an array. Maybe your "array" is really a string?

Comment: The 5 was a typo, I shortened the code from what i was using because i was passing 5 variables to the expect script and the 5th one was the one i was originally trying to access in the live code.

Comment: Take care with your expect commands: `lindex` returns a **single** element from a list; `array set` expects as its last argument **an even-numbered list of name-value pairs**. In Tcl/expect, an "array" is actually an **associative** array, and a "list" is a numerically-indexed array.

Answer (score 2):

**Sample.sh**

```
my_array=(1 2 3 4 5)
expect sample.exp "${my_array[@]}"
```

**Sample.exp**

```
foreach arg $argv { 
    puts "arg : $arg"   
}
```

**Output :**

```
dinesh@mypc:~$ ./sample.sh 
arg : 1
arg : 2
arg : 3
arg : 4
arg : 5
dinesh@mypc:~$
```

Comment: Quotes -- `"${my_array[@]}"` -- are needed to ensure that `my_array=( "first argument" "second argument" )` is treated distinctly from `my_array=( "first" "argument" "second" "argument" )`.

Comment: Question, If i am passing multiple values to the expect script, Would this be the correct way to call the variable?

foreach variable [lindex $argv 5]{
puts "variable equals : $variable"
}

I,m guessing there is a different way to do it since i am getting this error
`code`
wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"
    while executing
"foreach variable [lindex $argv 5]{"

Comment: As an update, i was able to get it to pass the variable correctly, but it still gives the error `code` wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command" `code` while trying to pass a variable "1 2 3".

Comment: in the sample.sh , second line can replace as
`tclsh sample.tcl "${my_array[@]}" "${my_arrayTWO[@]}" `
also works, thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @glenn jackman's comment...

Expect treats an Array as a set of key-pair values, while Expect treats a List simply as a list.

Therefore to be able to pass an array/list as a single arg...

**Array Example (myExpectArray.tcl)**

```
array set myArray [lindex $argv 0];
foreach item [array name myArray] {
  puts $myArray($item)
}
```

Call the expect script from command line...

```
myExpectArray.tcl "0 dog 1 cat 2 rabbit"
```

To call this from bash, you'd need to loop through the array and build the string to pass to the expect script. Using a List is easier...

**List Example (myExpectList.tcl)**

```
set myList [lindex $argv 0];
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $myList]} {incr i} {
  puts [lindex $myList $i]
}
```

Call the expect script from bash as follows...

```
myAnimals+=( "dog" "cat" "rabbit" )
myArgs=${myAnimals[@]}
myExpectList.tcl "$myArgs"
```

Note: You must convert the list ($myAnimals) to a string ($myArgs) otherwise Expect treats each element of the array as a unique arg.